# Windows 7 support for Mobile Intel 915GM/GMS, 910GML Express Chipset Family

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display

Are there any drivers compatible with Windows 7 for the Mobile Intel915GM/GMS, 910GML Express Chipset Family VGA adapter?

Intel's site says it is discontinued:

> http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=1862&DwnldID=18576&lang=eng

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue recently. I attempted to manually install a number of the drivers, including Vista-patched drivers, around on the Internet but Windows 7 would automatically remove the driver upon reboot.

I later found that you can use the standard Windows XP driver if you run the setup program in XP compatibility mode. The driver will install, but it still will not be able to detect the connected monitor, so you'll have to resort to standard screen resolutions, such as 1280x1024 or 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

They have the chipset drivers for W7, but no graphics driver is available.

See this possible resolution

http://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/3386-resolution-problem-intel-915-a.html

.

Comment: A bit more information might be useful to prevent this answer from becoming useless with bit rit. E.g. "Boot, <kbd>F8</kbd>, turn off driver sign enforcement, install the drivers in windows, reboot".

Comment: Bit rit, or bit rot?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the Vista drivers manually from the `*.inf` files; they should work on Windows 7.

Comment: Why would you make that assumption?

Comment: @soandos because Windows 7 uses the same graphic drive architecture as Vista.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into a shim. Shims allow you to trick a windows XP/Vista installer into running on a Win7 box. They're the "jedi mind tricks" of the IT world.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082(v=vs.85).aspx